# Intel HD Audio does not work after instaling linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic

Tags: drivers, sound, hda-intel

I let Sowfware Updater install what ever it wont. Now my audio does not work.
It seems that driver modules are not loaded correctly. Did anyone knows what is wrong or how to solve this issue?

```
lspci | grep Audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

sudo alsa reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
i915                 1130496  4
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
psmouse               126976  0
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 i915
e1000e                237568  0
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
sdhci_pci              24576  0
drm                   356352  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
video                  36864  1 i915
sdhci                  45056  2 sdhci_acpi,sdhci_pci
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid

locate snd-intel
/lib/modules/3.19.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-intel8x0.ko
/lib/modules/3.19.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-intel8x0m.ko
/lib/modules/3.19.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/soc/intel/sst/snd-intel-sst-acpi.ko
/lib/modules/3.19.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/soc/intel/sst/snd-intel-sst-core.ko
/lib/modules/4.2.0-22-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-intel8x0.ko
/lib/modules/4.2.0-22-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-intel8x0m.ko
/lib/modules/4.2.0-22-generic/kernel/sound/soc/intel/atom/sst/snd-intel-sst-acpi.ko
/lib/modules/4.2.0-22-generic/kernel/sound/soc/intel/atom/sst/snd-intel-sst-core.ko

dmesg
....
[    2.568967] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    2.569107] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
[    2.569198] systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
[    2.569272] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
[    2.569281] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[    2.569382] systemd[1]: Started Setup Virtual Console.
....
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic`
did the job.

Comment: Works with 4.4.0-83-generic in Ubuntu 16.04 but there is noise in headphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the solution there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1786495

Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dkms alsa-base pulseaudio`

Add the following line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1 enable=0,1 model=dell-headset-multi power_save=0 power_save_controller=N
```

reboot system (sudo alsa force-reload is not enought)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue.

The built-in speakers work fine, but headphones won't work.

```
lspci | grep Audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

I'll have to keep using 4.2.0-21 until this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I also confirm the issue on Kubuntu running the same kernel as above.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Solved the problem.

Comment: For me it was the missing driver from

     sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic

Mind the extra